# T-SQL Query to update a column with the number of occurrence of a value

Tags: t-sql

Below are the 2 sample columns from a bigger table :

[image]

I want to update the column B with the count of number of times the name appears in the column A.

So the result looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me with a T-SQL query for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't, use a `VIEW`. Storing aggregated values is rarely a good choice. As soon as you do any DML changes to the table, you have to recalculate the values.

Answer (score 0):

The query you need is a simple count using a window

```
select A, Count(*) over(partition by A) as B
from Table
```

However maintaing an aggregate is not a good idea, as commented it's better to create a *View* to return the correct values you need on the fly.

If you *really want to* you can use an updateable CTE:

```
with nope as (
  select *, Count(*) over(partition by A) as C
  from Table
)
update nope
set B = C
```

However you will appreciate as soon as a row is inserted/updated/deleted the values will be incorrect so you would have update them, hence the view is the better option as it always returns point-in-time data.